# Bootstrap Loginpage issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

hi all i am try to apply bootstrap css in my mvc application

i want reconstruct this example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/ in my application

i code my login page like

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h3>
      <input type="text" name="user_NA" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID"  />
      <input type="password" name="user_pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" />
</form>
```

but i got the output like 
[image]

i am not done any changes in bootstrap.css

i want tha black header(default). but here shows a button. please someon help me

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXjWV/2/)

```
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Good Luck..

Comment: it is correctly work in fiddle.. but in application, button is too longer

Comment: Send me URL or screen shot , If you can?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46724/discussion-between-pradeep-pansari-and-parvathiiiii)